# What module does this site use to handle its great badge system?

Tags: 7, users

Is this a functionality that exists within the existing badge module, or is it anything else?

Comment: are you talking about http://drupal.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I don't think this is a valid question. Either way I believe this site was build just like the other stack sites -- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Comment: The question is either a duplicate of [How can I get a badge system like on this site in Drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7978/how-to-show-users-tags) OR, as per @ericduran said, it's invalid in that it assumes this site is build on Drupal when it's not.

Answer (score 4):

This site (stackexchange.com) is not built with Drupal, but if you're looking for similar features in Drupal, check out [User Badges](http://drupal.org/project/user_badges), possibly in combination with [Userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) and/or [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).